# How Do I Move JSON and JS From Inside An HTML File To External Files?

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to move JSON and JavaScript from inside HTML into external files.

The following examples were a test I was running to make sure the data was being pulled in. Once I start adding in the actual data, the JSON and JS will grow and I don't want it cluttering the HTML.

That and there will be third parties editing the JSON data on an as needed basis so I don't want them doing that inside the HTML.

Here's the example at CodePen: http://codepen.io/frankDraws/pen/btvcr

Here's the code:

```js
var data = { "PreferredFlexPay":[
            {
                priceMonth:"$20.00 / Month",
                priceDownPayment:"$10.00 / Down Payment"
            }
    ]}

    // PREFERRED ANNUAL PASS FLEX PAY MONTH
var output='<span class="price-month">';
for (var i in data.PreferredFlexPay) {
    output+=data.PreferredFlexPay[i].priceMonth;
}
output+='</span>';
document.getElementById('preferred-FP-month').innerHTML=output;

// PREFERRED ANNUAL PASS FLEX PAY DOWNPAYMENT
var output='<span class="price-downpayment">';
for (var i in data.PreferredFlexPay) {
    output+=data.PreferredFlexPay[i].priceDownPayment;
}
output+='</span>';
document.getElementById('preferred-FP-downpayment').innerHTML=output;
```

```css
body, html {
    background: rgba(73,155,234,1);
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(0,81,168,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(73,155,234,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,81,168,1)));
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(0,81,168,1) 100%);
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(0,81,168,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(0,81,168,1) 100%);
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(0,81,168,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#499bea', endColorstr='#0051a8', GradientType=1 );
 background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font: normal 20px/1.8em Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: auto;
}
div {
  max-width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="fp-table">
    <tr><td id="preferred-FP-month"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="preferred-FP-downpayment"></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. I also don't see any JSON. `data` is a JavaScript object, not JSON. If you want the separate the data from the code, then simply store the data in its own file.

Comment: you put javascript files in some.js file, put your json in some.json file and you include or point according to their path. I don't get the point.

Comment: I did that but it's not working. This is how I linked them:

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/frontGate-data.json" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/frontGate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You put the JavaScript in its own file, traditionally with a `.js` extension, and refer to that file in the HTML using a `script` tag:

```
<script src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

(Anything you put between the start and end tag will be completely ignored by the browser.)

Similarly for the CSS (extension `.css`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourfile.css">
```

If you had JSON (you don't in your question, as Felix pointed out), that would typically go in a file with a `.json` extension and you'd load it via XHR (ajax). But typically if you have static data you want to use in your JavaScript, you just declare JavaScript variables and such directly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Apparently I'm not understanding the concept of JSON then. I thought JSON was the variable "data" and it's contents (i.e. priceMonth, etc). 

What I'd like to do is not have that object in the HTML, nor the JS. I know how to create links to external files. 

I created the links as usual but it stopped working. So I figured there's some other way of doing it since the conventional way wasn't working for me.

Do you follow?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it wasn't working. I needed to put the links to the external file at the bottom of the page before `</body>`.

Thank you all for the help! I love this community.